# What do you call a product that is on the shelf?

Tags: word-request

I see I didn't explain my question very well.

Let's say there are products on the market available for sale from suppliers. Those products exist and are in the world, but not on my shelf for sale at my company yet.

When I receive a supply of these products and put them on my shelf, is there a word that distinguishes them from before they were on my shelf? They are now "stocked items" or "in-stock products", as opposed to simply "products", yeah? Or  now maybe they are "inventory" now?

===== Original question =======

I'm trying to describe the relationship between

- conceptual products: ones that may or may not exist, and
- products that are stocked on a shelf

I'm wondering if there's a term.

Comment: You could call them "real" or "actual". In software terms, the ones that don't exist yet are sometimes called "vaporware".

Comment: conceptual products?? stocked products.

Comment: What do you mean by *may or may not exist*? Do time machines count? What do they have to do with the title of your question?

Comment: I like "stocked products" "in-stock" or "inventory" so far.

Answer (score 3):

There are loads of terms and idioms you could use.

- "On the market" refers to an item that is currently available for purchase, for example, "*products already on the market...*"
- You could just say "existing products" to refer to products that already exist.
- It is quite common to say that products are currently "on the shelves", which idiomatically means available in shops, particularly when something is widely available.

Products which are not yet on the market may be referred to as "in development", or "in beta" (usually technology, eg computer hardware or software, but sometimes used to refer to any product in early testing)

To draw a comparison you could possibly use any combination of the above, but my personal preference would be, for example, "*products currently in development, and those already on the market*".

Comment: And if a particular store has them for sale they are **in stock**.

Comment: To further confuse matters, things that exist and are on shelves are available "off-the-shelf", meaning ready to go without modification.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I did consider mentioning this but as you say, it would only confuse matters.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. conceptual products: ones that may or may not exist, and
> 2. products that are stocked on a shelf

The usual distinction in the UK is:

1. Available for order
2. In stock

If you mean by 1 that they really don't exist anywhere as a fully-formed usable product, then they are "in production" or "awaiting production".

Comment: *In stock* is used in North America too. The idea of *may or may not exist* is too vague for any kind of answer to be given. Does it mean it's possible they could exist somewhere? That they could be made on demand? Or does it include things like time machines, which nobody has and cannot be ordered?

Comment: I like "stocked products" "in-stock" or "inventory" so far.